# possible to strip second line from cell data in a mysql query

Tags: mysql

I want to strip any data paste the first line in a cell.

[image: Here is a screenshot of data in a cell, using Sequel Pro]

Is it possible in mysql to go thru each cell (in this case, field_id_60) and remove all data after the end of the first line?

This is what I want it to look like after the query is run (if possible)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ought to do it:

```
UPDATE `your_table`
  SET `field_id_60` = TRIM( TRAILING '\r'
                            FROM SUBSTRING_INDEX(`field_id_60` '\n', 1)
                      )
;
```

[`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) returns the value up to the first (`1`) given delimeter (`\n`) and [`TRIM(TRAILING '\r' ... )`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) will trim off any `\r` from the end in case there were any `\r\n` line breaks in your data. You might not need this latter at all, it depends where your data came from.